# How to limit the size of a textfile in Windows?

Tags: php, windows, gps, text-files

I'm maintaining a Windows 8 device with an embedded GPS receiver.

The GPS data are written into a location.txt file every second. The location.txt is then processed in some PHP scripts.

However, when the system is running for a longer time, the localhost gives me following error message: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted"

There is no possibility of changing the way location.txt is updated (e.g. by deleting the last record), as the GPS record software (called "u-center") is proprietary and does not have any customization interfaces. Record it or leave it.

Is there the possibility of a Windows script which automatically cuts the location.txt? The result should be the approx. 100 most recent lines only.

Thank you very much!
Stan

Comment: you could write a console app that opens a file, takes the first 100 lines of text, adds it to a new file, then deletes those first 100 lines from the original file.

Comment: not an answer to your question but you could also increase PHP's `memory_limit` setting to allow more wiggle room